# Open new session without a new tab (only with pinned tabs)

Tags: firefox

My Firefox profile has a setting "Show my windows and tabs from last time" set and I have several tabs pinned, but whenever I open a new session, instead of focusing on one of the pinned tabs (preferably the first one), it chooses to open a new tab which I don't need. Here is the screenshot for to understand the situation better:

[image: New tab opened for a new session]

This is what I want to have when I start a new session:

[image: Focus is on one of the existing tabs for a new session]

How do I prevent this new tab from being opened and have it focused on one of the pinned tabs instead?

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla changed Session Restore implementation recently and unintended or not this behavior is fixed.

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/33.0/releasenotes/